# Pivot tables - how to correct a date error

Tags: microsoft-excel

[Months go wrong after September](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk5yp.png)

I am having trouble with this issue where the dates start to go wrong after September. Instead of October, it says '>September'. I have selected 'this year' in the date filters so I'm not sure why it won't continue with 'October', 'November' and 'December' and is just bunching them all together as anything after September! I am a very basic Excel user so your simple replies would be appreciated!

Comment: Most likely, your data source is a text or csv file in which the date format is not the same as the format of your Windows Regional Settings. This problem is best solved by **importing** your data (do NOT **open** the file) at which time you can specify the format of the dates in the original data file. This problem and the reasons have been discussed many times in this and other forums.

Answer (score 0):

Better to recreate your pivot table. 
Not have seen your pivot table, just guess that may October, November, December are not clearly addressed in your source data.

Comment: This would be better as a comment asking for clarification / to provide data. This is not really an answer.